# Qual a diferença entre os handlers dos eventos no DOM?

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre, por exemplo, `<p onclick="fn()">click</p>`, `addEventListener('click', fn());` e `document.getElementById().onclick = fn();`.

Existe alguma relação com performance? Existe diferença de prioridade entre eles? Existe algum cenário especifico para cada um?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Funcionalmente, creio não haver diferença nenhuma entre ambos os métodos, tanto um como outro, irá executar a função `fn()` assim que esse elemento for clicado. As diferenças existentes entre os dois tipos, talvez seja mais em termos de limitações do que modo de operação.

```
<p onclick="fn()">click</p>
addEventListener('click', fn()); 
document.getElementById().onclick = fn();
```

Talvez devesses saber que essa forma de lidar com eventos, foi padronizada pelo *Netscape* ainda no **DOM Level 0**, para que pudessem executar eventos *Javascript*, e fora posteriormente adotada pelos mais variados navegadores. Só à partir do **DOM Level 2** foram introduzidos novos métodos, como o `addEventListener`.

As principais diferenças existentes para com o método tradicional *(onclick="...")*, são que vários manipuladores de eventos podem ser registrados para o mesmo evento, maior controle sobre quando o evento é acionado, e funciona com qualquer elemento DOM.

> Um equívoco comum com o modelo em linha é a crença
>   de que ele permite que o registro de manipuladores de eventos com
>   argumentos personalizados. [«1»](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events)

Sendo que o que realmente acontece é que o motor de JavaScript do navegador cria uma função anônima contendo as declarações existentes no atributo onclick.

Outro fato a considerar talvez seja a portabilidade que estes apresentam. Por exemplo, se quisermos mudar o nome da uma função vinculada a um evento de clique de um botão, teríamos que fazer as alterações diretamente no código *HTML*. Dentre estas existem ainda várias outras particularidades para cada, sendo que tanto um como outro, possuem vantagens e desvantagens em casos específicos.

Atualmente existem alguns problemas de compatibilidade para alguns dos padrões impostos pela W3C (DOM Level 3) e o IE8, por isso, alguns dos métodos podem não funcionar em certos navegadores.

## Algumas Referências:

- [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Older_way_to_register_event_listeners)
- [DOM (IE .spec)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771866(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [IntroEvents](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html)
- [OverView OEnH](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Overview_of_Events_and_Handlers)
- [HTML DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp)
- [DOM Events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events)

Comment: Na segunda e terceira linha de código, deverai ser `fn` ao invéz de `fn()`

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal faz algum tempo desde que respondi a pergunta, e a tua sugestão é também já muito antiga, mas de qualquer das formas responderei, escrevi `fn()` para simbolizar uma função, o mesmo poderia ser `function(callack){}` ou simplesmente interpretar `fn()` como uma função definida anteriormente, os parênteses são indicação de parâmetros nesse meu exemplo.

Answer (score 9):

A resposta do @Edilson tem uma abordagem teórica, vou tentar explicar na prática as diferenças.

Adicionar manipuladores de eventos (*event handlers*) com [atributo HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Event_attributes) ou com as [propriedades `.on*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers) tem as seguintes características:

- só é possível atribuir um único manipulador por evento e elemento
- para remover um manipulador basta configurar a propriedade como nulo ou *false*

A atribuição pelo atributo HTML tem as seguintes características além das descritas acima:

- vai contra a prática de [separação de conceitos (*Separation of concerns* - SoC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns#HTML.2C_CSS.2C_JavaScript), que visa separar exibição (HTML) e comportamento (javascript)
- não aceita funções anonimas (exceto *self executing anonymous function*)
- o [objeto `event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) estará acessível, tal como é com `this`, pois ao utilizar o atributo `onclick="exemplo();"` a propriedade `.onclick` do elemento terá o valor:

```js
function onclick(event) {
  exemplo();
}
```

---

Registrar uma espera de evento (*event listener*) com [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener) tem as seguintes características:

- é possível registrar mais de um *listener* por evento e elemento
- a remoção de *listeners* é feita pela função [`removeEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)
- remover *listeners* de funções anonimas só é possível de dentro da própria função utilizando [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee) como referência

---

Não existe um prioridade da execução por um dos métodos, as funções serão executadas na ordem que foram adicionadas.

Sobre performance, considero que a diferença seja irrelevante.

Answer (score 2):

Complementando as respostas dos rapazes e para ajudar as pessoas que quiserem ver a diferença de execução, vou deixar dois exemplos práticos que mostra a diferença entre o **onclick()** e o **addEventListenner()**.

Repare que no **onclick()** a função só é executada uma vez. Já no **addEventListenner()** as duas funções são executadas.

**Com onclick()**

```js
let element = document.querySelector("#botao");

element.onclick = function() {
  alert("Primeira função");
}
element.onclick = function() {
  alert("Segunda função");
}
```

```html
<button id="botao">Apertar</button>
```

**Com addEventListenner()**

```js
let element = document.querySelector("#botao");

element.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("Primeira função");
});

element.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("Segunda função");
});
```

```html
<button id="botao">Aperte</button>
```